# Strange behaviour with bluetooth discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am implementing an app with bluetooth.Here I am facing a strange problem.I want to show all the devices available when I scan my bluetooth.But my app is only discovering the bluetooth`s of pc.The bluetooth of mobile phones or tabs are not showing.To implement bluetooth functionality I have used [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/bluetooth/bluetoothadapter/android-bluetooth-example/) tutorial.Here is the code to find bluetooth devices:

```
  final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                 // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                 BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                 BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

   public void find(View view) {
       if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
           // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
           myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       }
       else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));    
        }    
   }
```

I have searched google but did not find any solution.Any help will be great.

Comment: Have you paired the device with the phone first?

Comment: Nopes.I have separate code to show paired device.

Comment: No I mean have you gone to settings(on the android device both receiver/transmitter side), found devices you want to pair with, done the acknowledgement then ran your app. Bluetooth is fussy with security protocols due to obvious concerns.

Comment: I downloaded the source code from the tutorial you mentioned and the app works fine.  I installed the app on my phone and When I press the "Search new Devices" button my tablet shows up.  You need to make the device that you want to connect to discoverable.

Comment: yeah got it...with the tab I was testing,it was only visible to paired devices...now it is working fine...goshhh

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that Bluetooth is enabled on the other devices.  Then make the other devices discoverable.  There should be an option in the bluetooth menu to make the device discoverable.  The device will only be discoverable temporarily (usually about 2 minutes).

Comment: my app meets all the criteria you mentioned above